# Better way to check for null in Java

Tags: java

I am checking for null value from the service which involves database transaction like this

```
if(!id.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || contactService.getContact(id) == null){ 
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
  }
Contact contact = contactService.getContact(id);
```

But by this way I am calling getContact service twice and its a overhead for the application , any better way to check for null value, so that I just need to call my service once.

Comment: Put it in a variable? Furthermore, (1) if your matcher fails, you should probably be throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, and (2) you should precompile that pattern instead of using it inline and compiling on every call.

Comment: good question... dont understand the downvotes too. maybe he is a beginner?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with people over SO nowadays; simply downvote even if it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's a valid programming question as far as I can tell

Comment: I downvoted and for me this question, even from a beginner, just reveal you have not checked this site or any other help prior to ask your question on SO.

Comment: I cant understand why guys down vote this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Contact contact;

if(!id.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || (contact = contactService.getContact(id)) == null){ 
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
}
```

Preferably, though, you should throw `IllegalArgumentException` instead if the ID doesn't match the approved format (since that's a different error than if there's no entry for a valid ID), and you should use `Pattern.compile` to save that pattern as a constant field instead of (1) recompiling it on every call and (2) hiding it as a magic constant deep inside your ode.

Answer (score 4):

do the `if` twice

```
if(!id.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){ 
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
  }
Contact contact = contactService.getContact(id);
if(contact == null){ 
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Contact contact = contactService.getContact(id);
if(!id.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || contact == null){ 
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
}
```